# VB.NET ADODB.Recordset and SQL Server 2019 Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 Collation hangs application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, utf-8, collation, adodb

I have a requirement to add UTF8 support in a legacy application that still uses ADODB and recordsets.  In sql server 2019, I have configured my db to use Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 collation.  Now, when I try to query my data into a recordset, my application just hangs.  I was able to pin point my issue to a line of code configuring the recordset.

```
Connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connect.Open(MyConnectionString) <== Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=Test
rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.ActiveConnection = Connect
rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly
rs.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly
rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient <== When set, causes the app to hang
rs.Open("SELECT columnName FROM dbo.table")  <== Assumes db collation is set to UTF8. When CursorLocation  is set to client, application will hang here
or
rs.Open("SELECT columnName COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 FROM dbo.table")  <== When CursorLocation is set to client, application will hang here
If rs.EOF = False Then  <== When CursorLocation is not set to client, application will hang here
    ...
End If
rs.Close()
conn.Close()
```

When I comment out that line of code, I'm able to load the recordset but as soon as I try to loop it, the application hangs again at the rs.EOF and I have to force quit.

Has anyone had any luck using the new UTF8 collation in SQL Server 2019 with ADODB?  Since the components are quite old, there is not too much out there in terms or support for them. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ADO is a wrapper over OleDb.  What OleDb provider are you using in your connection string?  The old SQLOLEDB, or the also old SQLNCLI, or the new MSOLEDBSQL?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Using Provider=SQLOLEDB.1

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  I didn't even notice the provider was still the old one.  Thanks for your help, this has definitely given me more to look at.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft can you provide your comment as an answer so I can mark this as "Answered".  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADO is a wrapper over OleDb, so you might be using an older OleDb provider like the old SQLOLEDB, or the also-old SQLNCLI.

For connecting to modern versions of SQL Server ADO applications should always use the new [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) aka MSOLEDBSQL.